# How to get DOM using d3.jsj or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I have drawn a svg using d3.js,However,I want to travel every node and get its `_data_` property.
I use this but it did not work.

```
$.each(d3.selectAll(".node"),function(index,values){
});
```

What should I do using d3 or jquery ? Please help me.

Comment: always provide your rendered HTML #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
d3.select("svg").selectAll("*").data();
```

Comment: But that results in an array of "undefined" elements,I am using sankey.

Comment: You haven't given us any idea of what you're actually doing, so this is the most specific answer I can provide.